# Basics of packaging Jruby on Rails for Tomcat

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

I have a sample rails app that works just fine when run normally. However, I cannot seem to get it packaged as a war that will deploy into Tomcat 7. Warbler seems to be not generating the web.xml file. What is the best way to package a simple war file that will run in Tomcat?

Comment: Warbler is almost certainly the best way.

Comment: can you post your warble.rb file?

Answer (score 0):

The book deploying Rails with Jruby has a good run down of this.

The basics are:

`warble config`

(generates the `warble.rb` file)

Adjust that file to suit your needs then:

`warble executable war` or just plain `warble` might work.

`warble -T` lists all the tasks that warble can do.

Inside the warble.rb file you can add options that show up on your web.xml file when the war is created.

For example this line:

`config.webxml.jruby.max.runtimes = 4`

puts the config option in the webxml.